# Files on SMB-Share are locked and some apps can't touch them

Tags: macos, permissions, file-sharing, smb, acl

Why do all files from a SMB share mounted on OSX are locked, generating Opearation not permiteted on some commands?

I have a Windows 7 x64 machine is providing a `share`.

The OS X 10.6 machine has mounted this share into `/Volumes/share`. I tested and I can add, delete and modify files from it using Finder or Midnight Commander.

Still, from some tools are failing to run giving errors like `Operation not permitted`.

The cause is the `locked` flag. I found that `find /Volumes/share -flags uchg`.

It seams the all the files that were modified from the OS X to get this flag by default.

Why is this happening (it shouldn't) and how to solve the problem? (probably requires modification of `/etc/smb.conf`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution at http://www.stanford.edu/group/macosxsig/blog/2010/01/snow_leopard_samba_and_nt_acl.html

This `feature/bug` is specific to `Snow Leopard - OS X 10.6`.

Modify `/etc/smb.conf` and add

```
[global]
acl check permissions = no
nt acl support = no
```

Do not forget to restart samba, or reboot after this.

To detect all locked files run:

```
find /path -flags uchg
```

To remove all locks from existing files run:

```
chflags -R nouchg /path/
```

Answer (score 1):

Realise this is an old q but hopefully this will help someone who ends up here.

I was having a similar problem on OSX 10.8.4. I managed to solve it by disabling indexing on the drive which contained the shared folder on the Windows 7 machine.

On Windows 7 "Computer" screen right-click the drive, go to Properties. Un-check "Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed..." Then click OK and in the popup choose "Apply changes to drive, subfolders and files"

Comment: Same problem happens on Windows 10, your answer helped me to find the cause. My question and answer on the Windows 10 version is linked to this one.